# Why can't Mobile Connect reports be automated for import?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, mobileconnect

Since no pre-defined reports are available, and the Contacts system table, although it contains all the necessary data, cannot be queried or exported for some reason, does anyone have a workaround so I don't have to manually pull the Mobile Connect deliverability report every day? I'd really like to automate the process for the client, and for us.

Comment: You may want to consider a custom engagement with ET Data Services, who can write you a custom report of your desired data.

Comment: For this a data view containing SMS send status that could be used with a query would be very helpful. I have just done investigation for documentation for this and unfortunately have been unable to find any information.

Answer (score 2):

If the MobileConnect deliverability report you're referring to is the SMS Detail Tracking Report in Data & Analysis -> Reports, then you can schedule this report to be e-mailed to one or many e-mail addresses at a regular interval.

You can also have the report saved to the enhanced ftp.

So instead of running the report from within MobileConnect, you need to head to the Data & Analysis -> Reports part of the app, which is separate from MobileConnect.

Comment: The new path is  `Analytics Builder > Reports`