# What are the data views names used for SMS tracking data?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, mobileconnect

I would like to write a query that uses the status of a SMS send. For query require SMS event time of send, details about if SMS failed plus any other useful SMS tracking data information.

For query require the data views names for where SMS tracking data is stored.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are no SMS activity [system data views](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/). The only SMS-related one that I'm aware of is the [SubscriberSMS](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_subscribersms/) view:

[image: SubscriberSMS SDV]

SFMC Data Architects can create system data views that you can use in your account.  It requires an engagement, but it can be cost-effective if your work-around solution is crazy.

Comment: Thanks @AdamSpriggs - there is now new system SMS data view that can help with reporting SMS - [_UndeliverableSms](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_undeliverable_sms/) and [usage example](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/mobileconnect/reviewing_message_activity_in_mobileconnect/retrieving_information_on_undelivered_sms_messages_for_mobileconnect/).

Comment: Refer to http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46282/why-cant-mobile-connect-reports-be-automated-for-import for discussion about how to use Analytics Builder > Reports to generate scheduled reports. This option allows for a SMS message detail report that can be scheduled for send to email or to enhanced FTP.