# MobileConnect SMS data to SF

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, mobileconnect, sms

If we use MobileConnect sends in Marketing Cloud, how can we get this data to SF?

There isn't much on the documentation.
Is using the REST API only way?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getMessageContactDelivery.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have Data View: [SubscriberSMS](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_subscribersms/) and you should Refer this answer as well https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/73039/20937